# Project Server 2013 Timesheet automatic approval

Tags: approval-process, project-server

I'm currently managing timesheets in Project Server 2013 but I've a problem when an user turns the timesheet into final timesheet.

I would like an approval from a Timesheet Manager but when an user turn it in final timesheet, the timesheet is automatically approved by the system.

I searched but everything I tried, failed (such as this solution) : http://blog.cps.co.uk/2013/07/29/timesheet-managers-in-project-server-2013/"

The Timesheet Managers is of course populated, the user who has the automatic approval is not a timesheet manager.

Maybe he is his own Timesheet Manager but I didn't find where to change this.

Answer (score 0):

I just find why the timesheet was automatically approved by the system, the user himself didn't have a Timesheet Manager in his resources information.

My mistake, I thought that by just adding Timesheet Manager in the PWA Settings, user will be link to these managers.